# Selenium - Webdriver executable doesnot exist error

Tags: java, selenium

I am getting below error while trying to execute my selenium code shown below:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Demo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "‪C:\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("www.google.com");
    }
}
```

> Error - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   The driver executable does not exist:
>   C:\Selenium\Introduction\‪C:\chromedriver     at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:585)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:146)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:141)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:159)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:355)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:94)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
>     at Demo.main(Demo.java:11)

I have placed the chrome driver in the location mentioned and the version is also double checked.

Answer (score 0):

This is very minor change with static mode, try with :

```
static WebDriver driver;
static String driverpath = "C:\\chromedriver.exe";

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverpath);
    driver = new ChromeDriver();    
}
```

As we are executing Java static main method, its requires to handle driver with Static variables.

Comment: but chromedriver.exe path is passed directly to setProperty method, still you think this is the issue ?

Comment: Yes, dependency with Static main method where it has been called

Comment: does that means, if it was same code was written in setUp() with testng, original post code would have worked without any change?